# How to convert <br> tag to <hr> tag with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have some variable like this;

```
<?php the_field('reviews'); ?>
```

This variable prints;

```
Some text 1
Some text 2
Some text 3
Some text 4
```

source code is here:

[image]

and look like this

[image]

Now, i want to convert **br** tag to **hr** like this

[image]

I tried the following ***[nospor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6356056/nospor)***'s codes but not worked.

```
$change = the_field('reviews');
$change = str_replace(array('<br>', '</br>'), array('', '<hr>'), $change);
echo $change;
```

How can i change that **br** tags to **hr** tag with PHP?

Comment: your `</br>` syntax is incorrect. you mean `<br>` or `<br/>`

Comment: Probably instead of `the_field` you should use `get_field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<br>Some text 1</br>` - wow.... who wrote that?

Anyway... do it as simple as possible ;)

```
$change = the_field('reviews');
$change = str_replace(array('<br>', '</br>'), array('', '<hr>'), $change);
echo $change;
```

edit:

Probably instead of `the_field` you should use `get_field` because first one displays it and second returns.

Comment: I add: <br> can't contain nothing (break row) so you can write <br> or <br/> it's the same. <hr> (horizontal row) of course the same, so <hr> or <hr/> for a xhtml like markup

Comment: I think `the_field()` function prints its contents where it is called. It does not return content as string.

Comment: Probably instead of `the_field` you should use `get_field`

Comment: i tried get_field function but not worked. i used your code, its working but there is no change about br tags. still putting br tags. so annoying :/

Comment: show **exactly** what returns get_field: `$change = get_field('reviews');var_dump($change);`

Comment: i shared my screenshot above. its exactly seems like that

Comment: Screen is result of `the_field`. I am asking of result `get_field`. I gave you a code to do that

Comment: same result. i tried both of two. this get_field and the_field functions about wordpress plugin Advanced Custom Fields. if its helps

Comment: also if you want to see that page, here it is : http://www.oyunfest.com/overwatch-inceleme.html . there is reviews section below.

Comment: On your website there is no <br></br>.... there is only <br />.... so my code should look likte this: `$change = get_field('reviews');
$change = str_replace(array('<br />', '<br/>')), '<hr>', $change);
echo $change;`

Comment: firefox has misled me, so sorry. your last code is working very well. so so thanks friend.

Comment: That's why I asked you for **exactly** result of `var_dump` not for print screen. Next time try to listen and use `show source code` instead of DOM review ;)

Answer (score 1):

`<br> </br>` is incorrect.

**HTML** `<br>` is an empty tag,so there is no end tag.

**XHTML** `<br />`

then you can use function `str_replace` to relace "br" by "hr"

```
$tag_br = array(
  "<br>",
  "</br>"
);
$tag_hr = array(
  "<hr>",
  ""
);
$change = str_replace($tag_br,$tag_hr ,$change);
```

Comment: That is incorrect, in XHTML br is denoted as `<br/>` as in XHTML every element has to be opened `<` and closed `/>`

Comment: @Martin I lost that condition, and i will modify the answer, thanks

Comment: Also if there is any "br" substring in the $change variable it will also turn into hr, lets say in the text we have "I will break your neck!" it will turn into "I will hreak your neck!" NOT a good practice. Do not hreck anyones neck please.

Comment: @BurakTokak yes it exist this problem terribly, continue to modify,thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37563100/3536236) is exactly correct.

You should use `str_replace`

the different between `str_replace` and `preg_replace`

```
$string = "foo fighters";
$str_replace = str_replace('foo','bar',$string);
$preg_replace = preg_replace('/f.{2}/','bar',$string);
echo 'str_replace: ' . $str_replace . ', preg_replace: ' . $preg_replace;
```

the output will be:

```
str_replace: bar fighters, preg_replace: bar barhters
```

Comment: You could / should perhaps add that the fundamental difference between the two functions is that preg_replace uses PCRE which is a very powerful tool whereas str_replace is simple sub-string recognition functionality. so for simple replacements as in this case then str_replace is far more efficient

Answer (score -3):

```
$string= the_field('reviews');
$change = str_replace(
  array('<br>', '</br>'), 
  array('<hr>', ''), 
  $string
);
echo $change;
```

Use simple php str_replace function